# SQL Query to Lambda C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, linq, lambda

What would be the Lambda statement for this SQL query?

```sql
update Table_Name
set Column_Name = REPLACE(REPLACE(Column_Name, CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ')
```

I already tried :

```
ExporttoExcel ete = new ExporttoExcel(); 
if (ete.BillingNotes != null) 
{ 
    ete.BillingNotes = ete.BillingNotes.Replace("\r", " "); 
    ete.BillingNotes = ete.BillingNotes.Replace("\n", " ");
} 
a.SubmitChanges();
```

Thank you!

Still no luck. Anyone?

Comment: show us what have you tried

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lambda expression to SQL UPDATE statement using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073464/lambda-expression-to-sql-update-statement-using-c-sharp)

Comment: Already tried :

ExporttoExcel ete = new ExporttoExcel();

                if(ete.BillingNotes != null)
                {
                    ete.BillingNotes = ete.BillingNotes.Replace("\r", "  ");
                    ete.BillingNotes = ete.BillingNotes.Replace("\n", "  ");
                }
a.SubmitChanges();

Comment: anyone can i have suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

here is just the samples:

```
var tb = db.Table_Name.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.Id == 1);
if(tb != null)
      tb.Column_Name = tb.Column_Name.Replace("\\r","").Replace("\\n","");
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll test it out.

CHAR(13) = \n
CHAR(10) = \r 

right?

Comment: No luck, i think the code you've given is just exactly the same as mine.
i cant still replace the "\n\r" OR char(13)/char(10)

Comment: still no luck, not sure why its not replacing.

Comment: anyone can i have suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Manage to fix using this :

a.ExecuteCommand("update ExporttoExcel set CardNotes = REPLACE(REPLACE(CardNotes, CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ')");

The variable "a" stands for DataContext.

Hope for other to help! thanks! :)